# Android 4.2.x not firing KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, keyevent, remote-control

In my application, I'm trying to implement handling of remote control button events such as:

```
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS
KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD
```

Everything works perfectly either using a BroadcastReceiver listening for `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON`, or by overriding `Activity.onKeyDown()`.

However, for some reason, on Android 4.2.2 devices, using a Bluetooth headset, we're not able to receive `KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD` events, using either method:

BroadcastReceiver: no event is generated

`Acitivity.onKeyDown()`: unknown KeyEvent (keyCode = 0) is generated.

Any idea why this happens and how to resolve this?

Android 4.2.x seems have an updated bluetooth stack, would this have anything to do with this?

Comment: In old bluetooth stack, bluez fast forward was not supported, though the headset was sending fast forward command, android was not able to recognize and execute that functionality, not sure about the Broadcomm stack

Comment: Actually, we're seeing the reverse behavior.  Fast forward works correctly on 2.3.x and 4.0.4 devices we've tested on, but not on 4.2.2